# Pandas: Adding single index dataframe ontop of multiindex dataframe by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Pretty new and inexperienced with pandas, but I feel like there's an answer here I'm just not quite seeing myself yet.
I have two dataframes, one with a single index and m number rows. The other dataframe has an unique m indices in it's first index, and can have a variable amount of indices in the second index.

Example:

`df_offset` DataFrame that I would like to add

```
    0
0   0
1   21080064
2   42729472
3   65017856
4   86253568
...
49  311934976
```

`df_epocs_idx` DataFrame I would like to add to:

```
        onset   offset
0   0   190722  923472
    1   2387988 3120738
    2   4585254 5318004
    3   6782520 7515270
    4   8979786 9712536
... ... ... ...
49  5   1289179 1313604
    6   1533320 1557745
    7   1777461 1801886
    8   2021602 2046027
    9   2265743 2290168
```

The result I would like:

```
        onset   offset
0   0   190722  923472
    1   2387988 3120738
    2   4585254 5318004
    3   6782520 7515270
    4   8979786 9712536
... ... ... ...
49  5   313224155 313248580,
    6   313468296 313492721,
    7   313712437 313736862,
    8   313956578 313981003,
    9   314200719 314225144
```

I have tried `df_epocs_idx.add(df_offset, axis='rows')` which gives an error: `ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names` and `df_epocs_idx.add(df_offset, axis='rows', level=0)` which just seems to add a new column to the front and then give me a bunch of NaNs.
I would like to avoid just using a for loop since I've learned that's usually inefficient when dealing with large dataframes, which in the future this might turn into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to assign the same column names to `df_offset` as in `df_epocs_idx`. Thus, create two columns in `df_offset` repeating the values you have now in your single column, changing the column names to "onset" and "offset".

I made up this example to reproduce your situation, and it may help you.

New dummy `df_epocs_idx`:

```
df_epocs_idx  = pd.DataFrame({'1': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1,1,2,2,2],'2': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1,2,0,1,2],
                 'onset': np.random.rand(9),"offset": np.random.rand(9)})

df_epocs_idx= df_epocs_idx.set_index(["1","2"])
df_epocs_idx

        onset    offset
1 2                    
0 0  0.100127  0.231690
  1  0.582593  0.209367
  2  0.598472  0.863339
1 0  0.079973  0.459830
  1  0.245197  0.874727
  2  0.717778  0.041785
2 0  0.750384  0.123909
  1  0.862120  0.169458
  2  0.056572  0.744763
```

New dummy `df_offset`:

```
df_offset = pd.DataFrame({"onset": [3,10,100],"offset":[3,10,100]})
df_offset

  onset offset
0   3   3
1   10  10
2   100 100
```

Sum the two dataframes based on level 0:

```
df_epocs_idx.add(df_offset, level=0)
```

Gives:

```
          onset      offset
1 2                        
0 0    3.100127    3.231690
  1    3.582593    3.209367
  2    3.598472    3.863339
1 0   10.079973   10.459830
  1   10.245197   10.874727
  2   10.717778   10.041785
2 0  100.750384  100.123909
  1  100.862120  100.169458
  2  100.056572  100.744763
```